# How to create virtual hosts in apache ubuntu 11.04

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, ubuntu-11.04

I want to create virtual hosts for my project in zend framework. I have frontend and backend (admin) functionality. I created the virtual host for my frontend functionality with necessary configuration and it running properly.

Example: In /etc/apache2/sites-available I created the file roomstays and my code is in **var/www** folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
DocumentRoot "/var/www/roomstays/public"    
ServerName localhost

#This should be omitted in the production environment
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<Directory "/var/www/roomstays/public">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

And it running properly with localhost.

Now I have admin i.e.backend code and as previous one I want to run this code. I put my newer code into same **var/www** directory with named roomstaysback. My question is how to create virtual host for this backend code. I want to run both frontend and backend side code.

Please give me any solution I am completely new in it thanks.....

Comment: Use google, Luke: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html

Answer (score 0):

You can handle both front end and back end from same virtual host. zend framework provides the concept of modules. Here is one example. Have a look

[Setup multi modules in Zend Framework v1.9 with 13 steps](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-general-discussions-1/resources-developers-37/setup-multi-modules-zend-framework-v1-9-13-steps-3737.html)

and the detailed one is here

[Using a Conventional Modular Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html)

Comment: Thanks Rajan..but I want to create separate virtual host for backend. So can it possible?

Comment: I can give you hint. What you can do is create separate virtual host for the back end and redirect all admin request coming at fron end to that backend virtual host

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a conf file for virtual host

```
$sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/HOST_NAME.conf
```

2.then paste following contents to this file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.HOST_NAME.com (set host name here)
    DocumentRoot /var/wwww/HOST_FOLDER (point to host path )
 </VirtualHost>
```

1. Add host name

   $sudo gedit /etc/hosts
2. Then paste following contents

   127.0.0.1   www.HOST_NAME.com
3. enable the site

   $sudo a2ensite HOST_NAME.conf
4. Restart apache server

   $sudo service apache2 reload

The process is over and you can browse www.HOST_NAME.com :)